# Vanisher plugin for Minecraft (Written with the Bukkit API)

Tags: java, minecraft

Would this code for my Vanisher plugin for the game Minecraft, written with the Bukkit API, be optimised and conventionally right?

**VanishAPI:**

```
package com.azoraqua.vanisher.api;

import com.azoraqua.vanisher.exception.VanishException;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.UUID;

public interface VanishAPI {

    void vanish(Player player) throws VanishException;

    void unVanish(Player player) throws VanishException;

    boolean isVanished(Player player);

    Collection<UUID> getVanished();
}
```

**Main:**

```
package com.azoraqua.vanisher;

import com.azoraqua.vanisher.api.VanishAPI;
import com.azoraqua.vanisher.command.VanishCommand;
import com.azoraqua.vanisher.command.VanishedCommand;
import com.azoraqua.vanisher.exception.VanishException;
import com.azoraqua.vanisher.listener.*;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.GameMode;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;

import java.util.*;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements VanishAPI {

    private static Main instance;
    private final List<UUID> vanished = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public final void onEnable() {
        Main.instance = this;

        getCommand("vanish").setExecutor(new VanishCommand());
        getCommand("vanished").setExecutor(new VanishedCommand());

        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerQuitListener(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerDropItemListener(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerPickupItemListener(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new BlockBreakListener(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new BlockPlaceListener(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerInteractListener(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onDisable() { }

    public static Main getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public final void vanish(Player player) throws VanishException {
        if(this.isVanished(player)) {
            throw new VanishException("Player is already vanished.");
        }

        vanished.add(player.getUniqueId());

        if(player.getGameMode() != GameMode.CREATIVE || player.getGameMode() != GameMode.SPECTATOR) {
            player.setAllowFlight(true);
            player.setFlying(true);
        }

        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.INVISIBILITY, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, false, false));
        Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().forEach((otherPlayer) -> otherPlayer.hidePlayer(player));
    }

    @Override
    public final void unVanish(Player player) throws VanishException {
        if(!this.isVanished(player)) {
            throw new VanishException("Player is not yet vanished.");
        }

        vanished.remove(player.getUniqueId());

        if(player.getGameMode() != GameMode.CREATIVE || player.getGameMode() != GameMode.SPECTATOR) {
            player.setAllowFlight(false);
            player.setFlying(false);
        }

        player.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.INVISIBILITY);
        Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().forEach((otherPlayer) -> otherPlayer.showPlayer(player));
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean isVanished(Player player) {
        return vanished.contains(player.getUniqueId());
    }

    @Override
    public final Collection<UUID> getVanished() {
        return Collections.checkedCollection(vanished, UUID.class);
    }
}
```

**VanishCommand:**

```
package com.azoraqua.vanisher.command;

import com.azoraqua.vanisher.Main;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import java.util.UUID;

public class VanishCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String s, String[] args) {
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            Player target;

            if (args.length > 0) {
                if(sender.hasPermission("vanisher.vanish.others")) {
                    String input = args[0];

                    if (input.matches("^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$")) {
                        target = Bukkit.getPlayer(UUID.fromString(input));
                    } else {
                        target = Bukkit.getPlayer(input);
                    }
                } else {
                    sender.sendMessage("§cYou cannot vanish other players. Missing permission '§bvanisher.vanish.others§c'.");
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                if(sender.hasPermission("vanisher.vanish")) {
                    target = player;
                } else {
                    sender.sendMessage("§cYou cannot vanish yourself. Missing permission '§bvanisher.vanish§c'.");
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if (target != null) {
                if (target.equals(player)) {
                    if(Main.getInstance().isVanished(player)) {
                        Main.getInstance().unVanish(player);
                        sender.sendMessage("§aYou have been unvanished.");
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        Main.getInstance().vanish(player);
                        sender.sendMessage("§aYou have been vanished.");
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(Main.getInstance().isVanished(target)) {
                        Main.getInstance().unVanish(target);
                        sender.sendMessage(String.format("§aYou have unvanished §b%s.", target.getName()));
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        Main.getInstance().vanish(target);
                        sender.sendMessage(String.format("§aYou have vanished §b%s.", target.getName()));
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                sender.sendMessage("§cThat player is not online.");
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**VanishedCommand:**

```
package com.azoraqua.vanisher.command;

import com.azoraqua.vanisher.Main;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.UUID;

public class VanishedCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String s, String[] args) {
        if(sender.hasPermission("vanisher.list")) {
            Collection<UUID> vanished = Main.getInstance().getVanished();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.format("§6Vanished Players (%s): ", vanished.size()));

            int checked = 0;

            for(UUID onlineUUID : vanished) {
                Player onlinePlayer = Bukkit.getPlayer(onlineUUID);

                sb.append(String.format("§8%s", onlinePlayer.getName()));
                checked++;

                if(checked < vanished.size()) {
                    sb.append("§f, §8");
                }
            }

            String list = sb.toString().trim();

            sender.sendMessage(list);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really interesting! I've never seen the source of a Minecraft mod before :)

#### Using a set

If you don't need the ability to store duplicate elements, sets are usually a better choice than lists. The most significant difference in this case is the `contains` method. It runs in constant time on a `HashSet` and linear time on an `ArrayList`. This is because the `ArrayList` has to walk through each element until it finds the searched element.  The `HashSet` only needs one lookup to decide if an element is contained within it.

In fact, when using a set there's much less need to call `contains` anyway. The `add` and `remove` methods return true if the operation went through and false if not. If you change the type of `vanished` to a set, you can omit the call to `isVanished` from both `vanish` and `unVanish`.

If you need more advice on which collection to use, check out this flowchart: [What Java Collection should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21974362/2073469)

#### Nested if statements

Having too many nested if statements can make code hard to read. I think the way you handle if statements in `vanish` and `unVanish` is the right way to do it.

```
if(this.isVanished(player)) {
    throw new VanishException("Player is already vanished.");
}
```

Here, you test for the error case and throw/return early. You could employ the same principle in the `onCommand` method to decrease indentation and improve readability.

1.

```
if (sender instanceof Player) {
    // ... 50 lines of code ...
}

return false;
```

2.

```
if (!sender instanceof Player) {
    return false;
}

// ... 50 lines of code ...

// nothing has returned?
return false;
```

In number 2 it's easier to see what happens in both cases. This refactoring can be applied in a couple of places in your code.

#### Methods are your friend

Don't be hesitant to split your methods up into smaller pieces! It can really improve how easily understandable it is. Because `VanishCommand.onCommand` is quite long and does several distinct tasks (parse sender name, check permissions etc), I think you should refactor it into smaller private methods.

Comment: I personally would add utility class(es) to do the command checks so. Because it's been used in multiple classes. Also I want to point out a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) doesn't have a 'get' method. Thank you though, I'll work on it immediatly. :)

Comment: @Azoraqua Ah, even better!

Comment: Created and added my own implementation of Set called [SmartSet](https://github.com/Azoraqua/Vanisher/blob/master/src/main/java/com/azoraqua/vanisher/util/SmartSet.java) (Even though it's not really smart ;)) and re-wrote my classes to make use of it.

Comment: Also, in additon to my latest comment (Because I can't edit it anymore): I have replaced all my if statements with checks with my utility methods from [BukkitValidation](https://github.com/Azoraqua/Vanisher/blob/master/src/main/java/com/azoraqua/vanisher/util/BukkitValidation.java) class.

Comment: @Azoraqua I looked at the linked code. I'm not sure why you have the `get` method and how you use it, but it seems dangerous. As far as I know, the `HashSet` iterator is not guaranteed to always return elements in the same order (so they get the same index).

Comment: Thank you for noticing me. That's pretty crucial information. I might rather put it back in the old implementation then, for safety.

Or atleast put it to an HashSet implementation, and hopefully I am not gonna use 'get'.

Comment: @Azoraqua If you *need* indexes, but I don't understand why. Isn't indexing by UUID enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47746/discussion-between-azoraqua-and-jacwah).